# What kind of test should be given to Java EE programmers?

Tags: interview, java-ee, tests

I'm looking to hire developers and I wish to test them. I have been especially told by my boss that we should have programmers on board that can consult on banking sector software and I'm to come up with the test. Now I've never done Java EE development in depth and my knowledge of it isn't the greatest but I've not had any trouble understanding what I've read so far.

Now I'm wondering how to construct a test to test candidates for Java EE knowledge as well as experience. And if I should make the test more conceptual like logical reasoning and pattern detection etc.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the job? Is it GUI development, or more technical stuff?

Comment: Both... We'll be developing web application architecture. Well I'm pushing for a php re-development solution but in the meantime we have to maintain the Java EE one and develop parts for it too. We also have to consult on J2EE dev for a banking client sometime in the not-so-distant future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**RESTful FizzBuzz**

Give them a computer, full access to the Internet, and a fresh install of Eclipse. Say to them that you'd like them to implement the [FizzBuzz](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/why-cant-programmers-program.html) program. Once they've completed that, ask them if they could create a RESTful web service that provides the FizzBuzz answer using a JAX-RS URI definition like this:

http://localhost:8080/FizzBuzz/{value}

Then sit with them as they go about it, asking and answering questions. If they can do that reasonably efficiently then you've got most of what you need to know.

Comment: Your answer whilst right on the money maybe more than we require (the part about RESTful is lost on me for the moment, and this is the part that's the "more") however I'm also considering giving conceptual tests at the interview like numerical reasoning (even though mine isn't the greatest) and pattern recognition (which I'm good at)

Answer (score 2):

Just listen ;)
They explain it to you in depth: Roundup '11 - Interviewing and Hiring Software Engineers Fully

http://javaposse.com/java-posse-368-roundup-11-interviewing-and-hiring
http://www.developerfusion.com/media/132147/roundup-11-interviewing-and-hiring/